# How do you access Mission 46?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, I know the ending mission is 46. How do you unlock the mission so you can play it and watch the ending?

Edit 1:

I got that ending but it still will not unlock for me. I got the cassette tape at the end and all.

Edit 2:

Here are the screenshots (MAJOR SPOILERS): steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=519951201 and steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=519951450 (Spoiler tags enabled for each)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [link](http://www.primagames.com/games/metal-gear-solid-5-phantom-pain/walkthrough/metal-gear-solid-5-mission-46-truth-man-who-sold-world), you are needing to have:

- Complete all of the main story missions (excluding the repeat missions) *before and after* this mission.
- You must also complete all of the important Side Ops indicated in **yellow**.
- Listen to all of the *yellow* cassette tapes
- You will need a fully upgraded Mother Base ***and*** all of its platforms.

If I remember correctly, there are about 49 total missions but Mission 46 marks the end of the story, Truth.

Due to comments, I will probably say a nearly fully upgraded Mother Base instead of a fully upgraded one. Maybe this link could help you unlock mission 46: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72466817

The text in it:

> To unlock Mission 46 "Truth: The Man Who Sold the World ", Phantom Pain's true final mission you need to meet certain requirements.
>
> **- Complete missions 1-31**
>
> **- Complete postgame Story Missions**
>
> Mission 32 To Know Too Much
>
> Mission 38 Extraordinary
>
> Mission 41 Proxy War Without End
>
> Mission 43 Shining Lights, Even In Death
>
> **- Complete postgame Side Ops Story Missions**
>
> Side Op - Extract the AI Pod
>
> Side Op - Secure the Remains of the Man on Fire
>
> Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 1
>
> Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 2
>
> Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 3
>
> Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 4
>
> Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 5
>
> **- Listen to all story audio/cassette recordings (they are yellow in colour)**
>
> **- Upgrade entire base, and platform to level 3 or higher.**

Answer (score 1):

To unlock Mission 46 "Truth: The Man Who Sold the World ", Phantom Pain's true final mission you need to meet certain requirements.

**- Complete missions 1-31**

**- Complete postgame Story Missions**

Mission 32 To Know Too Much

Mission 38 Extraordinary

Mission 41 Proxy War Without End

Mission 43 Shining Lights, Even In Death

**- Complete postgame Side Ops Story Missions**

Side Op - Extract the AI Pod

Side Op - Secure the Remains of the Man on Fire

Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 1

Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 2

Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 3

Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 4

Side Op - Search for the Escaped Children 5

**- Listen to all story audio/cassette recordings (they are yellow in colour)**

**- Upgrade entire base, and platform to level 3 or higher.**

Comment: This is a duplicate of what I have posted... Please give me credit for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to leave here my experience.

I had done mission 45 and side ops 150.

I did a lot of side ops but mission 46 wouldnt pop.

What I did was trigger all my tapes which were not heard and then did ONE side op.

Upon completion mission 46 immediately appeared in the list.

Mother Base had absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: This is more correct than the common methods you see listed nearly everywhere, as I am rather confident that most people are just copying the same incorrect steps listed everywhere. I feel the most commonly "unlisted" step is to do some side-op(s) AFTER all requirements are meant, as this is rarely ever listed.